Postgresql running Locally in Docker but not in the Cloud
Body
I'm facing an issue where I cannot establish a connection to my PostgreSQL instance running in a Docker container on my BW-Cloud instance. The error I receive when trying to execute a database query is:
"message": "connect ETIMEDOUT 193.197.228.168:5432"

Everything works fine when running locally, but for some reason, I am unable to connect from the cloud.
What I’ve tried so far:

I’ve tried to grep postgres on my VM, but it returns no output.
I’ve checked the firewall and security groups on BW-Cloud, ensuring that port 5432 is open for incoming connections.
I've verified that PostgreSQL is running inside the container using docker ps.
I’ve confirmed that the Docker container exposes the correct port 5432 to the host machine using the -p flag.
I’ve tried connecting both locally (inside the VM) and remotely, but neither work.

My Docker command for running PostgreSQL:
bash
sudo docker run --name db_container -e POSTGRES_USER=user -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRES_DB=mydatabase -p 5432:5432 -d postgres

Network and Firewall:
I have made sure that port 5432 is open on the cloud instance and mapped correctly.
The cloud provider does not seem to block any outgoing connections.
PostgreSQL Logs:
I couldn’t find any errors in the PostgreSQL logs, and the container starts without issues.
What is confusing:
Everything works locally, but the connection fails when trying to access the database remotely from BW-Cloud.
I’m not sure if it’s a network issue, a configuration issue within Docker, or an issue with BW-Cloud’s network setup.
Can anyone help me debug this further?
I’m pretty stuck at this point, and any help would be greatly appreciated!
